# BinaryFormatter seems to mess up with nested Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, serialization, binaryformatter

[Edit] I see that somewhy the post is downrated. I don't know why, but I'm sure that I did something wrong. So, please, if you have time, consider commenting and telling me what's wrong with the post please, before you downrateing it :) Thank you

So, I have this part of my Saving System in which I want to serialize a nested Dictionary given by a function called CaptureState. In my debugging, I check if CaptureState returns a Dictionary with a value under the key of SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex. It proves, that the method actually returns the desired Dictionary. However, if I serialize it and then deserialize it, the dictionary get's screwed up. It only contains 1 item(it supposed to contain 7), and that item is under the key 1 (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex is 0 at the time of testing) (these things don't reveal in the attached code, but believe me :D) And of course (as we can see in the attached code snippet), trying to access the key SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex(which is 0) throws me a KeyNotFoundException.
I use Unity if it matters.

```
 void SaveFile(string saveFile)
    {
        string path = GetPathFromSaveFile(saveFile);
        using(FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, CaptureState(LoadFile(path, stream, formatted)));
            //From this point, testing purposes
            stream.Position = 0;
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, object>> testDicta = (Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, object>>)CaptureState(LoadFile(path, stream, formatter));
            print(testDicta[SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex].Count); // Shows the proper count
            stream.Position = 0;
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, object>> testDict = (Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, object>>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            print(testDict[SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex].Count); // Throws me a KeyNotFoundException
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution.
The problem was that I started a Serialization, and passed in parameter containing a function which started a DeSerialization in the meantime. So they were Serializing and DeSerializeing at the same time, which caused the weird outcomes.